# Model appears inside-out with missing polygons in Eevee, but fine in Cycles

Tags: eevee-render-engine, normals

The model I'm creating has random polygons missing and appears almost entirely inside out when viewing in render preview mode with Eevee, but in Cycles render preview it appears completely fine. I even checked the orientation by enabling the option to color-code faces based on their facing direction, but all the polygons are facing the right way. This has nothing to do with the textures, as it still happens even when I remove the textures.

[image]

Comment: In the Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode > make sure it is set to Opaque and not Alpha Blend. If it still doesn't work please share your file